# ASP.NET Query database column with array of accepted keys

Tags: asp.net, database, many-to-many

I've reached a problem with query the database correctly. I can't find it answered anywhere else.

My datamaodel contains three tables one with the **Image** data and another with **tags**.
The third table joins the two tables creting a many to many relationship:

[Image] - 1 --- * ->[ImageTagJoin] <- * --- 1 - [Tag]

From a user input of a set of tags I want to get every image contaning all of the tags. The following code works for one tag

```
 viewModel.Tags = db.Tags.Where(
                            s =>
                                s.Name == searchString)
                         .Include(i => i.Images.Select( ii => ii.Image));
 viewModel.Images = t.Images.Select(x => x.Image);
```

The only solution I have is if, input is tag1, tag2, tag3, the controller iterated over each tag.

1. Get set of images with the tag tag1
2. From that set of images of tag1 get the subset of images with tag2
3. From that set get the subset of images with tag3

Now I have a set of images with the tags tag1, tag2 and tag3. Though that this solution works but not as elegant because it requires to search the database once for every tag and every image row gets looked up for every tag in the input.

Conclusion: How can I query a many-to-many relationship between images and tags, where I select all images that have the subset of n tags given from the user.

Thanks.

Comment: So do I have to call the database recursivly for each tag or is it a single call that will from a set of tags retrive all the images with a subset of those tags?

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of sweat and time I solved it. What I wanted was a IEnumreble from the database, an data stream not a collection wich is divided over each tag.

**Solution:**

```
/*
 * tagSet is an array of string with all the tags
 */
viewModel.Tags = db.Tags.Where(
                            s =>
                                tagSet.Contains(s.Name))
                         .Include(i => i.Images.Select(ii => ii.Image));

// a is the image, aa i the users inputted tag, aaa is the tag in the image
viewModel.Images = db.Images.Where( //All images..
                            a =>
                                viewModel.Tags.All( //..where every tag the user inputed ..
                                       aa => 
                                           a.Tags.Any(aaa => aaa.Tag.Name == aa.Name) //exist in the image set of tag
                                    )
                                );
```

First get a IEumreble with the tags the user inputed from the database. Then for every image that contans the set of all the users inputed tags in the set of tags related to the image. It works as I described it and as I understand it crafts one sql command that then returns the set of images from the database instead of the controller doing the lookup in an ICollection type of lookup.